# WPF. Анимирование кнопки и окружности в этой кнопке

Tags: wpf, анимация, storyboard

Имеется панель в тремя кнопками в ней. При наведении курсора на любую из кнопок воспроизводится анимация изменения цвета фона выделенной кнопки. Когда же курсор покидает границы кнопки, проигрывается анимация, возвращающая цвет фона выделенной кнопки в исходное состояние.

Во второй и третьей раскадровках выполняются те же изменения цвета, только уже для окружности.

Как сделать так, чтобы при наведении курсора на любую из кнопок воспроизводились анимации изменения цвета фона выделенной кнопки и изменения цвета фона окружности, которая находится в этой кнопке, а при выведении курсора за границы кнопки - цвета возвращались в исходное состояние?

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="4">

        <StackPanel.Resources>

            <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor1">#0A000000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ButtonBackgroundColor2">#3D000000</Color>

            <Color x:Key="EllipseFillColor1">#66000000</Color>
            <Color x:Key="EllipseFillColor2">#FF4CAF50</Color>

            <Color x:Key="TextBlockForegroundColor">#CC000000</Color>

            <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeBackgroundColorInButtonStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor1}"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor2}"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="ReturnBackgroundColorInButtonStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor2}"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundColor1}"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="ChangeFillColorInEllipseStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource EllipseFillColor1}"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{StaticResource EllipseFillColor2}"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Storyboard x:Key="ReturnFillColorInEllipseStoryboard">
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource EllipseFillColor2}"/>
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="{StaticResource EllipseFillColor1}"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource ButtonBackgroundColor1}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="16,8"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ChangeBackgroundColorInButtonStoryboard}"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ChangeFillColorInEllipseStoryboard}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ReturnBackgroundColorInButtonStoryboard}"/>
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ReturnFillColorInEllipseStoryboard}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
                <Setter Property="Fill">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource EllipseFillColor1}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4"/>
            </Style>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource TextBlockForegroundColor}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,4"/>
            </Style>

        </StackPanel.Resources>

        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 1"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 2"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

        <Button>
            <StackPanel>
                <Ellipse/>
                <TextBlock Text="Button 3"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
```

Выполнив данный код и наведя курсор на кнопку, появляется ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Свойство "Fill" не указывает на DependencyObject в пути "(0).(1)"."